# MonoForAndroid: android-support-v4.jar compile issue

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I just updated to Mono 4.4.41 and I'm getting compile errors related to the inclusion of the android-support-v4.jar file. The compile error I'm getting:

```
You have Jar libraries, android-support-v4.jar, that have the identical name with inconsistent file contents. Please make sure to remove any conflicting libraries in EmbeddedJar, InputJar and AndroidJavaLibrary.
```

The error occurs on Line 344 of Novell.MonoDroid.Common.targets (part of MonoDroid, not part of my project), in which it checks for duplicate jar files.

I have been using the support lib for weeks without any issues prior to the last update. I added it to my project according to these instructions:
http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Platform_Features/Fragments/Part_4_-_Providing_Backwards_Compatibility_with_the_Android_Support_Package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the support library jar from the project fixes this. It appears that Mono for Android now automatically binds the support library into the build, which resulted in duplicate jar files in the build. I looked through the recent release notes and this is all I could find that sounds relevant:

```
"Binding Projects now embed the bound .jar into the binding assembly."
```

From:
http://docs.xamarin.com/android/releases/Mono_For_Android_4/Mono_for_Android_4.2.8

Comment: Ran into the same issue now. So docs are still not updated and leading users into problems as I followd the docs by the letter, too.

Comment: The link now becomes 404, any updated link since it was an old answer?